# unbound variable in racket macro

Tags: macros, racket

I am testing a wrapper macro around the racket `syntax-case` macro. At step 1, it does nothing interesting and simply passes through all the parts to `syntax-case` directly as follows:

```
#lang racket

;; definition
(define-syntax guarded-syntax-case
  (lambda (x)
      (syntax-case x ()
        ((guarded-syntax-case y (literal ...) clause ...)
         #'(syntax-case y (literal ...) clause ...)
         ))))

;; test case
(define-syntax (binop stx)
  (guarded-syntax-case stx () ; *problem site*
        [(_ op n1 n2) #'(op n1 n2)]))
```

But this simple case fails with the following error at the empty brackets `()` labeled with *problem site* labeled in above code:

```
; ....rkt:11:27: #%app: missing procedure expression;
;  probably originally (), which is an illegal empty application
;   after encountering unbound identifier (which is possibly the real problem):
;    guarded-syntax-case
;   in: (#%app)
```

I couldn't figure out what could be wrong in this simple pass-through macro. The error message seems to suggest that there is a unbound variable somewhere, which I couldn't identify. I would think that the `literal ...` should be matched to empty.

*Could someone help explain what went wrong and how to fix the macro?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `guarded-syntax-case` is not recognized as a macro *in the correct phase*. In particular, when you `(define-syntax guarded-syntax-case ...)` in your program, you define the macro `guarded-syntax-case` that is available in phase 0. But forms in `(define-syntax (binop stx) ...)` must be in phase 1.

There are two ways to correct the mistake.

1. You can wrap `(define-syntax guarded-syntax-case ...)` inside `begin-for-syntax`. However, doing so would require `syntax-case` and other stuff to be available in phase 2. So you need an additional `(require (for-meta 2 racket/base))`. Here's the full code:

```
#lang racket

(require (for-meta 2 racket/base))

;; definition
(begin-for-syntax
  (define-syntax guarded-syntax-case
    (lambda (x)
      (syntax-case x ()
        ((guarded-syntax-case y (literal ...) clause ...)
         #'(syntax-case y (literal ...) clause ...))))))

;; test case
(define-syntax (binop stx)
  (guarded-syntax-case stx () ; *problem site*
                       [(_ op n1 n2) #'(op n1 n2)]))

(binop + 1 2) ;=> 3
```

2. Alternatively, you can define a (sub)module that provides `guarded-syntax-case`, and then `require` the (sub)module with `for-syntax`. Here's the full code:

```
#lang racket

(module lib racket
  (provide guarded-syntax-case)
  ;; definition
  (define-syntax guarded-syntax-case
    (lambda (x)
      (syntax-case x ()
        ((guarded-syntax-case y (literal ...) clause ...)
         #'(syntax-case y (literal ...) clause ...))))))

(require (for-syntax 'lib))

;; test case
(define-syntax (binop stx)
  (guarded-syntax-case stx () ; *problem site*
                       [(_ op n1 n2) #'(op n1 n2)]))

(binop + 1 2)
```